# How can I draw a tacking line on opencv

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, tracking

i'm using a code, in my Raspberry Pi, for tracking blue objects with a red circle. I'd like change the circle by lines. I've seen in opencv documentation I must put in function the initial and final coordinates for draw the line. How can I identify the points to draw it? I don't even know how i can to detect. Some ideas? 
 Following the code:

```
# import the necessary packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 50
camera.hflip = True

rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text
        image = frame.array

        blur = cv2.blur(image, (3,3))

        #hsv to complicate things, or stick with BGR
        #hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        #thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv,np.array((0, 200, 200)), np.array((20, 255, 255)))

        lower = np.array([76,31,4],dtype="uint8")
        #upper = np.array([225,88,50], dtype="uint8")
        upper = np.array([210,90,70], dtype="uint8")

        thresh = cv2.inRange(blur, lower, upper)
        thresh2 = thresh.copy()

        # find contours in the threshold image
        image, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        # finding contour with maximum area and store it as best_cnt
        max_area = 0
        best_cnt = 1
        for cnt in contours:
                area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
                if area > max_area:
                        max_area = area
                        best_cnt = cnt

        # finding centroids of best_cnt and draw a circle there
        M = cv2.moments(best_cnt)
        cx,cy = int(M['m10']/M['m00']), int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        #if best_cnt>1:
        cv2.circle(blur,(cx,cy),10,(0,0,255),-1)
        # show the frame
        cv2.imshow("Frame", blur)
        #cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh2)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

Comment: Check out this ball tracking algorithm. It display both a circle around the ball and a trail : http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/

Comment: I'm trying identify a blue object and I want follow the track of object drawing a line

Comment: So just change the HSV color mask to blue setting, and use the algorithm in this link ? maybe some parts have to be modify, but it's the same kind of line no ?

Answer (score 0):

If drawing a line along the path of the blue object is what you want, just draw it on your frame from the (cx,cy) of current frame to that of the previous frame. Make this change-

```
# import the necessary packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 50
camera.hflip = True

rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)


blank=np.zeros((640,480,3),dtype=np.uint8)
ocx=0  #initializing old centres
ocy=0  # this will draw a line from (0,0) to centre in the beginning
       # you can draw lines from second frame if you want to correct this


# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text
        image = frame.array

        blur = cv2.blur(image, (3,3))

        #hsv to complicate things, or stick with BGR
        #hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        #thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv,np.array((0, 200, 200)), np.array((20, 255, 255)))

        lower = np.array([76,31,4],dtype="uint8")
        #upper = np.array([225,88,50], dtype="uint8")
        upper = np.array([210,90,70], dtype="uint8")

        thresh = cv2.inRange(blur, lower, upper)
        thresh2 = thresh.copy()

        # find contours in the threshold image
        image, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        # finding contour with maximum area and store it as best_cnt
        max_area = 0
        best_cnt = 1
        for cnt in contours:
                area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
                if area > max_area:
                        max_area = area
                        best_cnt = cnt

        # finding centroids of best_cnt and draw a circle there
        M = cv2.moments(best_cnt)
        cx,cy = int(M['m10']/M['m00']), int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        #if best_cnt>1:

        cv2.line(blank,(ocx,ocy),(cx,cy),(255,255,255),5)
        out=cv2.add(blank,blur)
        ocx=cx
        ocy=cy

        # show the frame
        cv2.imshow("Frame", out)
        #cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh2)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

Comment: Unlike drawing a circle on each frame, if you want to retain the lines on a frame, just make a blank image before the while loop and then draw lines on it. If you want lines on your frame, then add the blank and the frame, i'll make changes in the code accordingly if that's the idea

Comment: thanks @I.Newton . My idea is retain the lines on frame for just shows the tracking. One thing: The While(1) I put it before loop for of my code? When you say "just make a blank image before the while loop and then draw lines on it", I need to use "blur = cv2.(image,(3,3)) and cv2.line" before while loop?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see the for loop earlier. Added the full code with changes.

Comment: thanks. I've test this code and the compiler shows me a error in line 73 in <module> out = cv2.add(blank, blur). Error: -209. The operation is neither "array to array" (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels). Do I change the size of array blank?

Comment: And I've tried print only the "blank" and I've got a error: PiCameraValueError: Incorrect buffer length for resolution 640x480

Comment: That should have worked. Basically, the blank image should have same size and channels as that of your adding image. Add this **print blur.shape[:3]** in your for loop and replace the blank value (640,480,3) to whatever you get in that. That should solve. As for your second error, check this [link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/08/29/common-errors-using-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module/) truncation problem